# A simple question on eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I started linear algebra this semester and I just had a thought.
A real number λ is an eigenvalue of A if and only if there is a non-zero vector x where (A-λ)x=0

Does that mean we can imply A=λ?

Comment: It is better to write $A-\lambda I$ instead of $A-\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

No, We can say $A=\lambda I$ if $Ax=\lambda x$ **for all** $x$, not just one non-zero $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote it wrong. $A$ is a transformation and to operate on it you need to change the form of $\lambda$ (a scalar). To do it, we need to transform it into a transformation too, which is why it's actually $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ or the transformation $A-\lambda I $ is not injective (since a transformation is injective iff $\operatorname{null} T=\{0\}$). What you said doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Let us contrast this with a different situation: let $a,b$ be real numbers, and $x$ a real variable. We do not want $x = 0$, so we assume otherwise. Consider now the equation

$$(a-b)x = 0$$

Now, I know where your intuition is going for this equation. Since $x \ne 0$, we can divide both sides by it, and thus conclude $a-b=0$, i.e. $a=b$.

It's not this simple in the more general case. The property we just used is called "right cancellation." We say we can cancel $x$ on the right if there exists some element $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1} = 1$, where $1$ is the identity with respect to multiplication in the structure we're working in. (Such structures include groups, for instance, which the nonzero real numbers can form under multiplication.) In the real numbers, this new element $x^{-1}$ is just $1/x$, which is always defined in the real numbers when $x \ne 0$. That's why we can do this in the above case.

However, not everything you deal with is a structure admitting such a property. For instance, matrices. We now consider your equation:

$$(A - \lambda I) x = 0$$

where $A$ is a matrix, $I$ the identity matrix, $\lambda$ a constant (from the field over which is the vector space we're dealing with), $x$ is a vector, and $0$ is the zero vector. If $A = \lambda I$, then there needs to be a vector $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1}$ is ... some sort of identity element. What that identity element is irrelevant because you can't even define the multiplication $xx^{-1}$: matrices need to have compatible dimensions to multiply in the usual way, but two vectors do not.

Thus, you cannot "divide" by the vector $x$ and conclude $A-\lambda I=0$. This is why we go the route through determinants instead when determining the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and eigenvectors $x$.

Answer (score 1):

No! Take a simple example. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is isomorphic to a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself. For a given vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $Ax$ is where the vector "lands" after the transformation. When we say $Ax = \lambda x$ for some scalar $\lambda$, it geometrically translates to the vector being elongated (if $|\lambda| > 1$) or compressed (if $|\lambda| < 1$). So, $\lambda$ measures the extent of elongation/compression, while $A$ is the transformation itself.